# Sign in with Firebase (current version) and Angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Could somebody provide me with an example of Firebase sigin/login with Email&Password. Eveything that I found seems to deprecated :(

Can you spot an error in this function?

```
 signup(email: string, password: string) {
    this._firebaseAuth
        .auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(value => {
            console.log('Success!', value);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
        });
}
```

and in app.component.ts

```
email: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}

  signup() {
    this.authService.signup(this.email, this.password);
    this.email = this.password = '';
  }
```

Comment: Assuming this is not a quiz question, you most likely get an error when you try to run this. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while too, here's what I found and it works well :)

Service:-

```
constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

/**
 *
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * @returns {Observable<any>}
 */
public loginUserObservable(email,password){ //but if still want to use an observable
    return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>> this.auth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)) // we need to cast the Promise because for some reason Angularfire returns firebase.Promise
}
```

Login Component:-

```
constructor(public authService: AuthService){}
public login(): void {
        let email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
        let password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;
        this.authService.loginUserObservable(email, password)
            .subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    this.response = response;
                    this._router.navigate(['/admin']);
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.failLogin = true;
                    this.handleError(error);
                }
            );
    }
```

Comment: Great, thank you - it works for loging but still doesn't for signing in. Could you please help with that as well?

Comment: What do you mean signing in? Isn't that the same as login?

Comment: Yeah, sorry :) I've meant signing up. Nevermind, I've managed to fix it. Your answer works, thank you once again.

Comment: No worries - why have you marked the other answer as correct then?

Answer (score 0):

[angularfire2 authentication](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md) makes it very simple

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

> npm install firebase angularfire2 --save

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

then...

```
password: string;
email: string;

constructor( private afAuth: AngularFireAuth ) {}

signupUser(email: string, password: string) {
 this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(
  error => console.log(error)
 );
}

signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
 this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
 .catch(
  error => console.log(error)
 );
}

logoutUser() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  this.user = null;
}


onSignin(signInForm: NgForm) {
  this.email = signInForm.value.email;
  this.password = signInForm.value.password;
  this.signinUser(this.email, this.password);
}

onSignup(signUpForm: NgForm) {
  this.email = signUpForm.value.email;
  this.password = signUpForm.value.password;
  this.signupUser(this.email, this.password);
}
```

your html would look something like this

```
 <form #signUpForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignup(signUpForm)">
    <md-card>
      <md-card-title>
        Sign Up
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-content>
        <md-form-field>
          <input mdInput id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email">
        </md-form-field>
        <md-form-field>
          <input mdInput id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
        </md-form-field>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions>
        <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </form>

 <form #signInForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignin(signInForm)">
    <md-card>
      <md-card-title>
        Sign Up
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-content>
        <md-form-field>
          <input mdInput id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email">
        </md-form-field>
        <md-form-field>
          <input mdInput id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
        </md-form-field>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions>
        <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </form>
```